# Seed production data in Rails on user creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a bunch of data created in seeds.rb for development purposes. Now I realized I basically need the same data to be created by default when a new user signs up on my website so he has not an empty account. What would be the best way to do it?

In my seeds.rb I'm creating a testing user and a bunch of objects for it. Can I somehow pass a user id to `Rails.application.load_seed`? Or is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't invoke `seeds.rb` upon user creation. Instead, `seeds.rb` should create the initial `User`-related models using the same method that the production app uses.

I can see at least two solutions to the problem:

1. Use the `after_create` callback on `User` to create the related objects. For example:

   ```
   class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     after_create :generate_api_key

     private

     def generate_api_key
       ApiKey.create!(user: self)
     end
   end
   ```

   In this case your `seeds.rb` can just call `User.create!(login: 'test1')`.  the related objects will be created automatically.
2. Create a service object `UserRegistrationService` responsible for creating `User` and it's related objects, e.g.:

   ```
   class UserRegistrationService
     def call(user_params)
       user = User.create!(user_params)
       ApiKey.create!(user: user)
       user
     end
   end
   ```

   In this case, `seeds.rb` should use the service to create the users. Instead of calling `User#create!` you should call `UserRegistrationService.new.call(login: 'test1')`.